# ArrayGame. Why doesn't it update the print?

Tags: c, arrays, logic, printf

This is my C Programming assignment. We're required to build a simple game that uses array. Our game is like the popular minesweeper game. At first, we initialise the 20*50 array area. Then we put some bombs randomly in the map. In the game, the player is required to travel from the starting point to the ending point to win the game. When the player moves, the movement will make the arrays hidden so that the user knows where did he start. However, in my case, the system doesn't update and make the array empty after the player  moves. Can anyone help me with my 's' code? What is wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define iMAX 20
#define jMAX 50
char array[20][50];
int i; //row
int j; //column
int z; //bomb
int n; //steps counter
int o; //x
int p; //y
o = 0;
p = 0;
int level;
int bomb;
char move;
int steps;

int main() {

printf("Welcome to the BombArray Game!\n");
printf("\nLevel 1 Begineer     : 50 bombs\nLevel 2 Intermediate : 100 bombs\nLevel 3 Advance      : 200 bombs\n");
printf("\nI want to challenge level ");
scanf_s("%d", &level);
printf("\n");

srand(time(NULL));

for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
        array[i][j] = '*';
    }
}

array[0][0] = 'S';
array[19][49] = 'E';

if (level == 1) {
    bomb = 50;
}

else if (level == 2) {
    bomb = 100;
}

else if (level == 3) {
    bomb = 200;
}

for (z = 0; z < bomb; z++) {
    i = rand() % 20;
    j = rand() % 50;
    array[i][j] = '1';
}

do {
system("cls");

for (i = 0; i < iMAX; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < jMAX; j++) {
        if (array[i][j] == 'S') {
            printf("S");
        }
        else if (array[i][j] == '*') {
            printf("*");
        }
        else if (array[i][j] == '1') {
            printf("*");
        }
        else if (array[i][j] == 'E') {
            printf("E");
        }
        else if (array[i][j] == '2') {
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

printf("\n\nMoving direction (w:up s:down a:left d:right  e:exit): ");
scanf_s(" %c", &move);
printf("Steps? ");
scanf_s("%d", &steps);

if (move == 's') {
    for (n = 0; n < steps; n++) {
        i = o;
        j = p;
        i++;
        array[i][j] = '2';
        o = i;
        p = j;
    }
}


} while (array[19][49] != 2);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Why do you use so much global variables?

Comment: Does making them local fix my problem?

Comment: You can try, but i don't think so. `o = 0;` and `p = 0;` outside of main give me a compiler error.

Comment: I made them local but the problem still exists.

Comment: I don't get any compiler error..

Comment: `scanf_s(" %c", &move);` --> `scanf_s(" %c", &move, 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (move == 's') {
  array[o][p] = '2';  
  for (n = 0; n < steps; n++) {   
    i = o;
    j = p;
    i++;
    array[i][j] = '2';
    o = i;
    p = j;
  }
  array[o][p] = 'S';
}
```

You have to delete the S at the Start position and write it at the end position when you move

Some additional things: You don't need that much variables. You can remove `i` and `j` (or `o` and `p`).
If you enter something others than 1-3 for the level you will have an undefined number of bombs (if you declare the `bomb` variable as a local variable), therefore you should make a default case.

You never look if you are hitting a bomb, you just overwrite `array[i][j]` without prove if there's a bomb.

better:

```
if (move == 's') {
  array[i][j] = '2';  
  for (n = 0; n < steps; n++) {
    i++;
    if (array[i][j] == '1') {
      printf("bomb\n");
      return 0;
    }
    array[i][j] = '2';
  }
  array[i][j] = 'S';
}
```